Bootstrap DateTimePicker Not Displaying Correctly in Responsive Table with Overflow Handling
I'm trying to create a responsive table with Bootstrap that includes DateTimePicker widgets in some cells. The table should have horizontal scrolling when needed, but I'm struggling to get the DateTimePickers to display correctly when the table is inside a container with overflow handling.
Here's the problem:
If I use overflow: visible !important; for the table container, the DateTimePicker widget displays properly, but the table loses its responsive behavior.
If I set overflow-y: hidden;, the table becomes responsive, but the DateTimePicker widget is partially covered and doesn't display fully outside the container.
If I remove the overflow settings entirely, the DateTimePicker is confined within the container, resulting in an awkward vertical scroll.
I'm looking for a solution that allows the table to remain responsive with horizontal scrolling, while also ensuring that the DateTimePicker widgets overflow correctly and display fully.
Here is the relevant HTML and CSS:
<div class="box-body table-container">
    <table class="table wrap-text-table" id="operationalBreakdownTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="p-2">#</th>
                <th class="p-2">Start Time</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="operationalBreakdownList" class="draggable-rows" data-bind="foreach: operationalBreakdownList">
            <tr class="draggable-row" data-bind="attr: { 'data-id': id() }">
                <td>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="input-group date picker-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-toggle="datetimepicker" data-bind="timepicker: startTime, attr: { 'id': 'startTime-' + id() }" autocomplete="off" />
                        <div class="input-group-append" data-bind="attr: { 'data-target': '#startTime-' + id() }" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-clock"></i></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<style>
.table-container {
    overflow-x: auto; /* Enable horizontal scrolling */
    overflow-y: hidden; /* Disable vertical scrolling */
    position: relative; /* Make the container relative for z-index positioning */
    overflow: visible !important;
}

    .table-container table {
        width: 100%; /* Full width of the container */
        border-collapse: collapse; /* Collapse borders */
    }

        /* Styling for table cells */
        .table-container table td,
        .table-container table th {
            white-space: nowrap; /* Prevent text wrapping */
            border: 1px solid #ccc; /* Add borders */
            padding: 8px; /* Padding for cells */
            text-align: center; /* Center align text */
            width: 8%; /* Set a fixed width for all columns */
        }

/* DateTime picker styles */
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget {
    z-index: 1050; /* Higher z-index to ensure it appears above other elements */
    position: absolute; /* Position absolutely */
}

    .bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table th, .bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table td {
        border: initial;
        width: initial;
        padding: initial;
    }
</style>

What I've Tried
Tweaking the overflow properties in the container's CSS.
Adjusting the z-index of the DateTimePicker widget.
Wrapping the DateTimePicker in different containers to control its overflow.
Desired Outcome
I want the table to maintain its responsive behavior, with horizontal scrolling enabled when necessary, and the DateTimePicker widgets should overflow outside the table container without being cut off.
Is there a way to achieve both responsive table behavior and proper DateTimePicker overflow handling? Any advice or insights would be greatly appreciated!
